# how to have a second form on the same django page that can retrieve the id of the first (uncreated) form?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'll try to keep it simple:
I have a first form named hira, which comes from the class Hira in my **models.py** :

```py
class Hira(models.Model):
    pbs = models.ForeignKey(PBS, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    function_Mode = models.ManyToManyField(FunctionMode)
    building = models.ManyToManyField(Building)
    hazard = models.ForeignKey(Hazard, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='activity_hazard')
    failure_Mode = models.ForeignKey(FailureMode, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='activity_failuremode')
    activity = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    risk_Description = models.TextField(default="")

    @property
    def physical_control(self):
        fulldescr = ""
        for m in MitigationMeasure.objects.all():
            if m.mitigationType == "PHY" and m.related_hira_id == self.id:
                fulldescr += "# " + m.description + "\n"
        if fulldescr == "":
            fulldescr = "No physical control recorded."
        return fulldescr

    @property
    def robust_counter(self):
        counter = 0
        for m in MitigationMeasure.objects.all():
            if m.related_hira_id == self.id:
                counter += 1
        return counter
```

The **MitigationMeasure** class :

```py
class MitigationMeasure(models.Model):
    Related_hira_id = models.ForeignKey('Hira', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=999999)
    Description = models.TextField(default="")
    Types = (
        ("PHY", "Physical"),
        ("ADM", "Administrative"),
        ("INS", "Instrumented"),
    )
    MitigationType = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        choices=Types,
        default='PHY'
    )
    Implemented = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    Robust = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I currently have a page displaying the form for hira, and I'd like to be able to add a button to this same page that is adding mitigation measures (and thus create a form containing information from the MitigationMeasures class).

simplified **html** file  :

```html
{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row  mt-5">
            <div class="col-md-6 w-100">
                <div class="border p-3 bg-white">
                    <h2>Edit Hira</h2>
                    <hr style="min-height:5px">
                    {% if submitted %}
                        Your HIRA was saved successfully !
                    {% else %}
                        <form  action="" method=POST class = "post-form">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                            <!-- General Elements -->
                            <div class="row p-4">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <label>PBS :</label>
                                    {{form.pbs}}
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <label>Function Mode :</label>
                                    {{form.function_Mode}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
.
.
.
.
.

                            <!-- Inherent Risk -->
                            <div class="row p-4 ">
                                <div class="text-center text-white fw-bolder" style="background:#7986CB">
                                        <p >Inherent Risk</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <label>Physical control :</label>
                                        <div class="form-group border rounded p-1 ">
                                            <p style="font-size:1rem"{{hira.physical_control|linebreaksbr}</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row p-4  col-md-3 mx-auto">
                                <input class="btn btn-success text-white fw-bolder" type="submit" value="Edit" name="normal">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

current **view.py** :

```
def form(request):
    submitted = False
    if request.POST:
        hiraform = HiraForm(request.POST)
        if hiraform.is_valid():
            hiraform.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/form?submitted=True')
    else:
        hiraform = HiraForm
        if 'submitted' in request.GET:
            submitted = True
    return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': hiraform, 'submitted': submitted})
```

The first problem is that, being new to django, I don't know how to manage 2 forms on the same page.

The second problem is that for my properties to work, the hira must already be created so that I can assign an id to my MitigationMeasures. (The fact is, I'm supposed to be able to fill in the hira form and still be able to add measures, which will be displayed in a read-only format on the hira form page once they've been created).

Moreover, I'll need the second property for further calculations, which is why counting the number of robust measurements is important.

My method may not be the right one, which is why i need help and advice.

Comment: I would recommend that you only have one form on the page to keep the code much simpler and more readable. You could redirect the user to the second page after the first object is saved, and then you will be able to provide the ID automatically in a hidden field. General rule of thumb, simple is good.